# Why is issuing a trap not a priviledged task?

Tags: operating-system, assembly-trap

In solutions to a question on the book "Operating Systems Concepts" it indicates that issuing a trap not a privileged task. Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some instructions need special privileges to run at all, which most of the time means only the OS gets to execute them.

Most user processes (programs) will need to issue a trap / exception to get the OS to run these instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If it were a privileged operation, it wouldn't be possible for a process to issue a system call.